# Is $R[x]/(x^2)$ isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I guess no, because $x^3$ is not divisible by $x^2$, but I am not sure whether it is right to think in this way or not.

Remarks:

R[x] denotes the set of all polynomials with coefficients in R.
$R[x]/(x^2)$ is the quotient ring.

Comment: is $R$ a ring ?

Comment: Yes, they are both rings.

Comment: Either I am missing something or this is true by recognizing they both contain $0$ as the only root.

Comment: Isomorphic as rings or as R-modules?

Comment: Isomorphic as rings.
But i am also interested to know what  are the differences between isomorphic as rings or as R-modules?

Comment: If $R$ is a commutative unitary ring, then $R[X]/(X^2)$ is a free $R$-module of rank $2$, while $R[X]/(X^3)$ is a free $R$-module of rank $3$. Therefore they are not isomorphic as $R$-modules.

Answer (score 4):

If $R=\Bbb Q[x_1,x_2,\dots;y_1,y_2,\dots]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,\dots;y_1^3,y_2^3,\dots)$, I believe that $R[x]/(x^2)\cong R[x]/(x^3)$ (and indeed both quotients are isomorphic to $R$ itself).

Comment: Sorry for not stating clearly. 
$R[x]$ denotes the set of all polynomials with coefficients in R.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the map defined by sending $x$ to $x_1$ and $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ is an isomorphism of rings from $R[x]/(x^2)$ to $R$?

Comment: @AbhinavVNatarajan I believe so.